# Collaboration between Token and coin

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, tokens

I have some confusions regarding Token and Coin.

Form my understanding, **Token** are built top on some blockchains like Ethereum for crowdfunding. That **Token** has a name itself let say "" (A to Z token). Lets assume that crowdfunding is successful.

Now that team build their project and create their own **Coin** on their own real blockchain. Lets say that coin name is "ZAT" (Z to A token).

Now my question is how can the AZT(in Ethereum)and ZAT(own blockchain) can be exchanged? What can investor do with the AZT token(From ethereum) when there is actual  coin ZAT (blockchain) from that team.

What are the similarities and dissimilarities between Crypto token and coin.

NB: Pardon me if I have been asked a very silly question.

Answer (score 1):

1) The company can freeze ZAT tokens (in Ethereum) and airdrop AZT tokens (on their blockchain) to investors.

2) Use centralized exchanges to do the exchange

3) Create a pegged system where a smart contract (assuming this new blockchain has smart contract abilities) exists both on the EVM and the new company's blockchain. 
These smart contracts, along with an oracle type system, will coordinate the transfer of ZAT tokens (locked into that contract on Ethereum) and then the smart contract handling AZT tokens will release tokens to a specified address. There are many ways to skin this cat, so to speak.

[Rootstock](https://www.rsk.co/) has a pegged system into BTC.

Comment: can you give me some article links related to this ?

Comment: Please check the edits also